# App engine, Flask-Socketio server Cors_Allowed_Origins header is missing

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

When I try to send a request from the client to my socketio flask server that is deployed on app engine I recieve the following error:

has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I did put the following line in my python server script:

```
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins='*')
```

I also added the folling line:

```
CORS(app)
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried changing the app.yaml with the Allow_cors_origin of the url handler, installing flask-cors package, nothing worked

EDIT:
I found in the app engine the following message while debugging:

{
"textPayload": "The client is using an unsupported version of the Socket.IO or Engine.IO protocols (further occurrences of this error will be logged with level INFO)",
"insertId": "5fca5af900064b8faf6f9267",
"resource": {
"type": "gae_app",
"labels": {
"module_id": "default",
"project_id": "island-battles",
"version_id": "20201204t174848",
"zone": "europe-west6-3"
}
},
"timestamp": "2020-12-04T15:51:21.412559Z",
"labels": {
"clone_id": "00c61b117cf0689fb08fabba9037f4624c77b480da8e9472be2b02038e0fe7d2d8dcac81021c"
},
"logName": "projects/island-battles/logs/stderr",
"receiveTimestamp": "2020-12-04T15:51:21.465294012Z"
}

How do I fix this? Thanks

SECOND EDIT:
Everything works fine in my local version, the problem lies with app engine

Comment: This might [help](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_http_headers)

Comment: add this in your yaml file `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://your_deployed_website.com`

Comment: @GuneshShanbhag, My game is cross platform, so it's not only one url

Comment: @GuneshShanbhag also, I tried writing in the app.yaml file what it said in the docs, didn't work for me. I need the requests to work on the main file, not the static files

Comment: [Do go through this too](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/2196)

Comment: Hey, this didn't work either, I am using long polling on purpose

Comment: @GuneshShanbhag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is due to an unsupported Socket IO version. I imagine you are using the [latest version](https://pypi.org/project/python-socketio/), however, App Engine usually takes some time to support the latest versions. Try [downgrading](https://pypi.org/project/python-socketio/#history) it to v3.x, maybe even v2.x.

You can install specific versions of packages with `$ pip install <PACKAGE>==<VERSION>`, in this case, for example: `$ pip install python-socketio==3.1.2`.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Flask-SocketIO make sure to install a compatible version, the latest is not compatible with python-socketio 3.1.2 and you will get an error.

I ran:

```
pip install python-socketio==3.1.2
```

as suggested by Oliver but had error because I had Flask-SocketIO version 5.0.1, so I ran the following:

```
pip install flask-socketio==4.3.2
```

and that solved my issues.

Ultimately you'd want flask-socketio-4.3.2 python-engineio-3.14.2 python-socketio-4.6.1

Similar conclusion reached here:
https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/1432
https://github.com/juharris/switch-remoteplay/issues/37

Answer (score 0):

Bycors_allowed_origins option

For examplehttp://127.0.0.1:8283,server.py script

```
sio = socketio.Server(cors_allowed_origins='http://127.0.0.1:8283')
```